# Java: Incorrect time zone in Files.getLastModifiedTime

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to print out the last modified time of a file. Somehow, the timestamp returned is incorrect and different from the system time.

`Files.getLastModifiedTime(Paths.get(directory, filename))`

which prints
`2019-01-14T11:48:47.312493Z`

System time is in fact:

```
LocalDateTime.now()  <- 2019-01-14T19:48:50.495242600
```

How can I overcome this problem and make `getLastModifiedTime` returns the time in my local timezone?

Comment: The time is correct - as you can see from the last character `Z` (incidentally, you probably made a copy-paste error, as it should be a capital Z), the time is in "Zulu" time zone - in other words, UTC. The other time is a local time in your local timezone.

Comment: according to the docs, "representing the time the file was last modified, or an implementation specific default when a time stamp to indicate the time of last modification is not supported  by the file system" does your file system support the timestamp?

Comment: I mean I can right click and see the properties of a file and see that the last modified time has changed or not. I am guessing it means my file system support timestamp then ?

Answer (score 2):

`LocalDateTime` is, as the name says, the *local* date and time. It depends on the timezone configured on the machine. The machine probably runs in UTC+8. To get a timezone-less datetime, like `getLastModifiedTime()` returns, use `Instant.now()` instead of `LocalDateTime.now()`.

Alternatively you can convert the `Instant` returned by `getLastModifiedTime(...).toInstant()` to your local date time:

```
Instant modified = Files
    .getLastModifiedTime(Paths.get(directory, filename))
    .toInstant();
LocalDateTime modifiedDateTime = modified
    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    .toLocalDateTime();
```

where `ZoneId.systemDefault()` is the system's default configured timezone. You could also use a fixed timezone like `ZoneId.of("CST")` for China Standard Time for example. But I strongly recommend to always work with `Instant` where possible, because then you cannot accidentially compare datetimes from different timestamps, and avoid errors due to different environments the code runs on.

Comment: `Files.getLastModifiedTime` returns a `FileTime` object, not an `Instant`

Comment: *" It depends on the timezone configured on the machine."* ... Not necessarily. `LocalDateTime` has no dependence on any time zone at all.  It represents *some* local date and time.  It can not be made to represent any point on the time line until it is associated with an offset or a time zone, but that time zone may be arbitrarily defined and needn't be the one configured by the machine.

Answer (score 2):

Seems  `FileTime#toString()` returns datetime string is in `UTC`, here is a piece of  it's source code:

```
ldt = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(lo - SECONDS_0000_TO_1970, nanos, ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

You can get the `Instant` from `FileTime` then convert it to `LocalDateTime` with system time zone:

```
FileTime fileTime = Files.getLastModifiedTime(Paths.get(directory, filename));
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(fileTime.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```